# Find: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, find, escape-characters

Why does

```
$ while true ; do 'date; time find /tmp/test -type f \
  -exec cp /dev/null {} \;';sleep 3600; done
```

not work and instead return an error message:

```
-bash: date; time find /tmp/test -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} \;: No such file or directory
```

I have tried escaping `;` and `{}` but I still get the same error. And yes, there is a `/tmp/test` directory.

Comment: why you put it in the single quote?

Comment: The error in the title is wrong. Should really be `-bash: ...: No such file or directory`.  `find` never executes, so it can't give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes and it will work as expected (and yes, you must have two semi colons in a row).

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `do` is a single command; further commands use a command chain.

```
while true ; do date ; find ... ; sleep 3600 ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while true; do
    date
    time find /tmp/test -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
    sleep 3600
done
```

The single quotes in your command makes the shell interpret the quoted string as the name of a command to execute, and it can't find it, which is why you get that specific error.

Another way of doing the emptying of files under `/tmp/test` every hour is via a cronjob with the following schedule:

```
0 * * * * find /tmp/test -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```